# Get Location of Referenced local Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have ProjectA referenced by ProjectB in my solution. I'm trying to get a "path" of ProjectA, when running ProjectB.

I've tried this:

**Running in ProjectB**

```
// HomeController is in ProjectA
// This code is executed from ProjectB
var assembly = typeof(HomeController ).Assembly;
string filePath = new Uri(assembly.CodeBase).LocalPath;
```

Returns ProjectB path, instead of ProjectA path.

EDIT:
This shows UnitTestProject1 in the path. I want to get a path to WebApplication1.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get location of referenced assembly use this

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SmsController)).Location;
```

Comment: So, are you sure that `SmsController` from ProjectA? It works you just need to pass type from assembly

Comment: Yes. SmSController is inside ProjectA. I have simple solution with 2 projects. That's it. One is Web, the other is UnitTests. UnitTests references Web

Comment: @ShaneKm It is ok, because your referenced dll copy to bin of running project. So, it shows path to assembly that using (from bin folder). If you wanna just path to Web project then you can see in .csproj file and find `ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\ProjectA.csproj"` and use something like that

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to ensure that the file you want to reference is copied to the bin folder of your project B (main project).  Then you can use this code:

```
    string code = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
    UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(code);
    string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
    return Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
```

This returns the path to your bin folder.

I think you would have to add the file you want to reference as either an embeeded resource or a linked resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht9h2dk8(v=vs.100).aspx